# Electrochemical double layer formation

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

I was revisiting some of my notes about the electrochemical double layer but I have some doubts, and even the textbook of Bard and Faulkner could not really help.

In electrochemical systems, at the potential of zero charge (PZC) there is no charge on the electrode surface and therefore no electrochemical double layer as I understand it (it is the maximum of the following graph, potential vs surface tension):

[image]

Using the PZC now as our reference point where there is no double layer, if we shift the applied potential on the electrode to more positive values than the PZC (assume there is no faradaic reaction, only capacitive effects) of course, a double layer forms. Now my question is:

If the applied potential is more positive than the PZC, does that mean, that the electrode is positively polarized due to the applied potential and anions are moving closer to the electrode surface? Or if the applied potential is more negative than the PZC the electrode is negatively polarized and more cations are near the electrode, or is a metal electrode generally positively polarized?

So does the “sign” of the electrode’s charge have something to do with the potential that we apply, or is the EDL independent of the applied potential (should be Helmholz assumption)?

Comment: Yes, if you apply a negative potential compared to the PZC the electrode will carry excess negative charge, vice versa for a positive potential compared to PZC. More details can be found in Bard Chapter 13 ( this part on excess charge and PZC is in section 2.2). The excess charge on your electrode is definitely dependent on the applied potential, a basic theory hinting at this is already Gouy Chapman, now of course with specific adsorption and different metal facets this becomes a very complicated issue.

Comment: Okay I will take a look at chapter 13. I was thinking it should be at earlier chapters in the book because it is a very important topic!!

Comment: I can also give you the points for a bounty if you answer the question because it helped me a lot

Comment: I feel like a complete answer that's nuanced would take me a real while to write and the comment is not answer worthy, so I'll just be happy that you have the resources to answer your question now.

Comment: Ok thank you for the effort tho.